# python-Dataframe count rows with condition

Tags: python, dataframe, spyder

I have a python code that is collecting information from a dataframe (df1) like this

```
for ind, data in enumerate(df1.Link):
         print(data)
         
         
         result = getInformation(driver, links)
         
         for i in result['information']:
             df1.loc[ind, "numOfWorkers"] = i["numOfWorkers"]
```

the output is saved to a dataframe like the one shown in the photo:
[image: photo of final output]

Is there anyway to update my code before it returns the dataframe with this condition:
if noOfWorkers >=30, once we have 2 links that have this condition, the code will break and return the result

can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to put the logic in the code you already have. I would keep a count of the number of records matching the conditions, then exit out of the loop using break (rather than a while loop):

```
     ...
     workers_threshold = 30
     records_matching_threshold = 0
     max_records_for_matching_records = 2
     for i in result['information']:
         df1.loc[ind, "numOfWorkers"] = i["numOfWorkers"]
         if i["numOfWorkers"] > workers_threshold:
             records_matching_threshold += 1
         if records_matching_threshold > max_records_for_matching_records:
             break
```

Note that the variable names above are purposefully long to make their purposes clear in my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 2
while i != 0:
    if numOfWorkers >= 30:
        i- = 1
```

Comment: thank you for answering. Do you think it should be in the loop ? (for i in result['information']) ?

Comment: A few problems with this code: `i` is already being used for something else; numOfWorkers is not actually set; there is no need to use the while loop (we're already inside a loop); this has the potential to become an infinite loop if used incorrectly.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's just to show him what the program should do, I never code in place of the others it prevents them from learning